# JavaFX SceneBuilder alternative

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder, gluon

I have been facing serious issues with Scene Builder as it seems to freeze my desktop. Are there any alternative drag and drop GUI builders for JavaFX? Something like Android Studio where you can quickly switch between "Design" and "Text" would be really helpful.

Comment: try intellij idea.

Comment: Netbeans has this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the [Intellj IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) as it provides integrated an SceneBuilder that allows you two quickly switch between text and design. Android Studio is built on top of Intellij so you will notice a lot of similarities between the two IDEs.
 [image: Intellj]

Comment: Two years after, but yes, inside intelij is build in scene builder :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) is very comfortable you can also add design libraries like [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) that facilitate your work. You must install depending on the JDK that you are using in your project to compile.